# C# overload and override method

Tags: c#, overriding, overloading

I have a class that extends another class and I would like to override and overload a method the same way it is done in a constructor.

Something like this (This is just to illustrate what I want):

```
public class A {
    someMethod(int i){
        //Do something
    }
}

public class B : A {
     someMethod(int i, int j) : base(i){
         //Do something more
     }
}
```

How can I reproduce something like that ?

Comment: Is `someMethod` public? protected?

Comment: Start by specifying access modifiers to your functions...

Comment: and apply [.NET naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members), no lowercase method names, so pascal- not camel casing.

Comment: That wasn't real code, just an illustration of what I'm trying to do ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the inherited method from within the child-class, this approach would be called overloading (adding a method with the same name but different parameters):

```
public class A 
{
    // note that the method must not be private 
    // in order to be able to call it from intherited classes
    protected void someMethod(int i){
        //Do something
    }
}

public class B : A {
     // however, this class may be private of it needs to be
     void someMethod(int i, int j) 
     {
         this.someMethod(i); 
         // Do something more
     }
}
```

You could also write `base.someMethod(i);` or don't write any specifier at all, because it is redundant, but personally, I find `this` more explicit than omitting the specifier. In this specific case, it doesn't really matter.

**However**, if you override the method in your inherited class using `this` (or omitting the specifier) would call the overridden one while using `base` would call the implementation of the base class so you might want to pay attention to that detail.

---

Just to point out the differences. **Overloading** would be like "swapping out" or to be more specific, modify or extend the implementation in a inherited class, while keeping the originate signature of the method (name and parameters):

```
public class A 
{
    // again, note that the method must not be private 
    // in order to be able to call it from intherited classes
    protected virtual void someMethod(int i){
        //Do something
    }
}

public class B : A {
     protected override void someMethod(int i) 
     {
         this.someMethod(i); 
         // Do something more
     }
}
```

Comment: `protected void someMethod(int i){..}` by default the method is `private`

Comment: in `this.someMethod(i); ` keyword `this` is *redundant*

Comment: It does not work : B.someMethod(int, int) is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override

Comment: You say it's more convenient, but `this.someMethod` and `base.someMethod` are potentially very different things.

Comment: you are right, i edited the answer

Comment: edited my comment, tried to do a newline, posted comment instead

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I dunno, I find `this` useful to differentiate between class-based stuff and local variables.

Comment: There are different number of parameters in these methods. Consider using the same number of parameters and their types while overriding. Remove `int j` from overriden method...

Comment: @McKay you are right, I'll edit my answer to celarify the differences

Comment: Ok, thanks for the corrections it works :)

Comment: @MarkBenovsky That's not the question, though. This isn't about overrides. It's about calling functions from the parent class. Which is nothing special at all, except the function needs to be accessible, so at least `protected`.

Comment: @Nyerguds Agreed, but still the example is confusing. Why not make it correctly?

Comment: @MarkBenovsky because, from the original example using constructor overloads calling another constructor, the point is to add an _overload_ on the child class, with the same name but with more parameters, which starts with calling the original function.

Comment: you guys are quick with commenting, I wasn't even done yet :D

Comment: You are still saying the thing about `this` being convenient, that's really bad advice.

Comment: @DavidG De gustibus et coloribus non est disputandum. It's useless to fill this comments section with bickering about that, imo.

Comment: @Nyerguds omg I was confused by comment `marked as an override but no suitable method found to override`, not it makes sense

Comment: @Nyerguds This isn't an argument about taste, it's about providing *good* solid advice to people who don't know any better. There's no bickering here.

Comment: @nozzleman I think you are getting confused between overloading an doverriding now, overloading is not about "swapping out" anything.

Comment: @DavidG I once again edited the answer to make my point clearer.

Comment: @DavidG I think it would be "more convinient" if you could collect your comments and rephrase them into a better answer than mine. This way, the OP and future readers would not need to search for the fragmented wisdom in the comment section of this answer ;)

Comment: No need, your answer is on it's way to being fine, just needs the incorrect bits changing.